# Propositional calculus, Post-completeness and beyond

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

For a homework, our professor gave us the following problem: Prove that propositional calculus is Post-complete (term is not in English I am literally translating it), which means that if we add anything that isn't a theorem to propositional calculus as a scheme (or I think the phrase I need is axiom of propositional calculus) the system becomes inconsistent.

Now, this is my first post here, but I have been using this site quite a lot. My English isn't the greatest out there, but I hope that my question is understandable. Ofc, if prove requires use of natural deduction or Hilberts system, I think I am capable of following in both systems.

To be fair, actually I dont have a clue where to start, since I did have a whole lot of pause when it comes to logic, and Set Theory is what I find more appealing. :D

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ an unprovable *schema* of propositional calculus with $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ propositional variables.

By [(semantic) completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)#Semantic_completeness) of the calculus, being unprovable implies that $U$ is not a *tautology*.

Thus, there is a valuation $v$ such that $v(U)=\bot$.

Add the schema $U$ as axiom, and consider its istance $B$ obtained replacing in $U$ each $p_i$ with $p \to p$, if $p_i$ is evaluated to $\top$ by the valuation $v$ above, and with $\lnot (p \to p)$ if $p_i$ is evaluated to $\bot$.

Obviously, the resulting formula $B$ is a theorem, being a substitution instance of an axiom of the "enlarged" system.

But $B$ is always false; therefore, $\lnot B$ is a *tautology*.

By completeness $\lnot B$ is provable in the enlarged system, and thus both $B$ and $\lnot B$ are theorems.

Conclusion: the enlarged system is *inconsistent*.

---

*Added Feb,14*

A different proof, derived from  David Hilbert and Wilhelm Ackermann's [Grundzüge der theoretischen Logik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Mathematical_Logic), 1st German ed., 1928 [see the [English translation of the 2nd ed, 1937](https://books.google.it/books?id=45ZGMjV9vfcC&printsec=frontcover), page 43].

Let $A$ be any formula which is not provable from the axioms. Let $B$ be the 
corresponding formula expressed in [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form). Since $A$
is unprovable, also $B$ is.

Being unprovable, in $B$ we have at least a conjunct $C$ that is a disjunction containing no mutually contradictory literals.

If in $C$ we put $p$ for every un-negated sentential symbol and $\lnot p$ for every negated sentential symbol, we obtain a disjunction of the form $p \lor p \lor \ldots \lor p$, which is equivalent to $p$.

If now we add $A$ as a new axiom, we have that $B$ will be provable in the enlarged system, as well as $C$ and finally also $p$.

But then we could also substitute $\lnot p$ for $p$, obtaining a contradiction.

Comment: Thx a lot, sry for not being able to vote up your reply. :(


Kinda bumped now that I can see such a compact and precise answer. Can I bother you some more, and ask for an idea of the proof, if we dont use completeness?

Comment: @Ay-jay Without completeness this would be *much* harder ... in fact, you'd effectively be proving completeness while answering this question.

Comment: @Bram28 Though so, would be incredibly tricky job.